# Daf Yomi and half of Shas

Tags: daf-yomi, shas, calculation

I'm currently learning Daf Yomi and am considering doing a second daf everyday but would like to start at a daf that is half way through Shas from where we are currently holding. So that I could complete it every 3.5 years. Does anyone have a easy way to calculate this?
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that if we are at 50% of the way through, you want to start at 75% of the way through?

Comment: @RabbiKaii I think he means if we're at 25%, where is 75%?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but we're well over halfway through Shas by now (the middle daf was Kiddushin 39, in early Tishrei). Today's daf, Bava Metzia 11, was the 1527th daf of Shas, with 1184 to go. So if from here on out you learn 2 dafim a day, then those 1184 dafim would take you 592 days, and you'd finish on 1 Cheshvan 5786, when everyone else is learning Zevachim 39.

Comment: I think he is asking that, if we are at 50%, where is 75% so he can follow along daf yomi while learning the "second half from where we stand" in parallel to finish earlier. In any case, we shouldn't have to guess what the OP means. Please [edit] the question to make it clearer

Comment: And Moshe, a belated welcome to MiYodeya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Here seems to be a good daf yomi calculator. Never used it, can't vouch for it, but it seems to let you play with the parameters in the right way https://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=1